# Does Mypy disregard constructors?

Tags: python, types, mypy

I want to use Mypy to warn me when I accidentally change a variable to a different data type.
But it seems Mypy ignores anything that happens in the `__init__` of my test class.
It also ignores a change of an object's attributes to different data types.

Minimal reproducer:

```
class Foo:
    blah: int
    def __init__(self):
        self.blah = 'asdf'
```

Mypy [reports no issues](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=4bdc8df021ac8b142be364fdc6f58698) for this code.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mypy` ignores the body of any `def` statement without type annotations. Annotating any parameter or using the [`--check-untyped-defs` flag](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#untyped-definitions-and-calls) causes `mypy` to inspect `__init__` and reject incorrect assignments.

```
class Foo:
    blah: int
    blub: int

    # annotated parameter `blub` and/or return `->` trigger inspection
    def __init__(self, blub: int = 42) -> None:
        self.blah = 'asdf'  # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
        self.blub = blub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It finally works the way I want it to. :) Just a short follow-up question: Does "blah: int" outside the __init__ not care if blah is an instance, class or static attribtue?

Comment: Annotations at class scope indicate *instance* variables by default. A class attribute must be annotated at class scope as ``blah: ClassVar[int]``.